# Can we add extra method in java.lang.Object?

Tags: java, object, lang

We have a set of methods defined in `java.lang.Object`. And every class extending this class automatically.

How to add a method in `java.lang.Object` class?

Comment: You can extends Object class. Why you want to do that?

Comment: http://blog.vinceliu.com/2007/07/having-fun-with-javalangobject.html

Comment: Even if it were possible, I think that would be a bad decision. What makes your method so important, that each and every object inherits from yours needs this method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462472/add-a-field-to-java-lang-object

Comment: I came across this post because I really miss Smalltalks "yourself" identity function. My Java code would be cleaner if I could end a chain of method calls with "yourself()" and get back the receiver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No (only by tinkering with rt.jar or bootclasspath), and why would you want to do that when you can write your own class that - by definition - `extends Object`?

If the "need" arises to add methods to an existing class (in particular something in the JRE libraries) that is usually an indication that your design/object model isn't sound. Show us why you want to do this and we can help you better.

I understand from a comment on another answer that you want to print information about "unknown" objects. This is exactly what [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) is for. If you override that method on your own classes, you can control the output exactly, rather than the usual `name@hash`. This is of course assuming that you're not throwing just *anything* into the methods in question, but only classes  *you* control...

Cheers,

Comment: Yes you are right I can define any class by extending object but some time when i am calling some functions that time i don't know actually what type of FORMAL arguments are coming into that function because of genric programming . So By default (without type casting) I can call functions which is defined in object class. So I need to add 1-2 more functions in java.lang.Object class .

Comment: If you bound generics with `Object` you're really not using generics. Show an example please, and we can work from there.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by others: the answer to your question is No if avoid changing the original code...

I don't know your application, but in case you like to add "Aspects" you might want to take a look to AspectJ: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AspectJ

Comment: Yes , exactly I want to use aspect and in aspect i want to use one common function which can print the related information about that object because in aspect we will have all argument as object.So this is the main reason i want to define one particular function for AOP

Answer (score 2):

Technically you can but there is a number of problems.

- it violates your license agreement for Oracle JDK, possibly others.
- you have to add your new version to the start of your `bootclasspath` or `endorsed` directory which is a pain.
- you can only add a couple of methods before the JVM crashes.  It makes some assumptions about the Object class and some other commonly used classes.

I would only do this for investigation purposes and not use it in production.

Comment: Can you provide me any document or any online page which can tell me how to add some methods before JVM crashes.

Comment: @PankajGoyal Its not as magical as you might imagine.  Take a copy of the source, edit it, compile it, and prepend it to the bootclasspath (see the java command line options)

Answer (score 0):

**No!** you cannot add your custom functions in `java.lang.Object` class.

Comment: With your own runtime, you can.

Comment: Can please give me any hint how can i have my own runtime.

Comment: @soulseekah's link is dead.