# Saving stack trace in java for any object at the time of it's creation and using it at any other point in the program

Tags: java, stack-trace

For debugging purpose, I want to save the stack trace when an object was created and refer/print it at a later point in the program.  I tried adding a field to Object class in OpenJDK itself but as mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462472/add-a-field-to-java-lang-object) it will cause a problem with hard coded elements in OpenJDK.

Can someone please suggest an efficient way to do this.

Comment: Do you have control over the code which calls the constructor of the object you want to create? Do you have control over the constructor of the object you want to create?

Comment: If it’s for debugging purposes, why not set a break point?

Comment: @Progman yes i do have control over the code and constructor

Comment: If taking a stack trace on object creation isn't sufficient/appropriate for the issue you're trying to solve, it might help to give a few more details of what the actual problem is?

Comment: I needed stack trace to study the lifetime of the objects for a humongous, memory and CPU intensive application, but now I understand it will very expencive. Can you suggest an alternate approach. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collecting a stack trace for any object, and storing that information with the object that simply isn't possible in an efficient manner.

Collecting stack trace information is **expensive**, and there is no way to do that "on scale", as part of normal program execution. Keep in mind that the primary purpose of stack traces is to collect that information after an exception occurred.

Beyond that, it is also conceptually wrong. If you only talk about very few specific objects, then the appropriate approach would be to carefully study the paths in your code that create these objects, and maybe have the code that creates objects do extensive logging. But if you really talk about many different sort of objects, then your request rather implies that the overall logging concept in your code is insufficient. Focus on that part then.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I understand it will be very expensive. But I needed stack trace to study the lifetime of the objects for a humongous, memory and CPU intensive application. Can you suggest some better approach than getting the stack traces?

Answer (score 2):

If the object is large, or frequent, JFR will sample the allocation. By default it samples up to 150 times/s.

JDK 16, or later:

```
$ java -XX:StartFlightRecording:filename=exitdump.jfr MyApp
...
Stop the application
$ jfr print --events ObjectAllocationSample --stack-depth 64 exitdump.jfr

jdk.ObjectAllocationSample {
  startTime = 12:00:19.826
  objectClass = byte[] (classLoader = bootstrap)
  weight = 23.1 kB
  eventThread = "Image Animator 0" (javaThreadId = 33)
  stackTrace = [
    sun.awt.image.GifFrame.dispose() line: 723
    sun.awt.image.GifImageDecoder.produceImage() line: 247
    sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch() line: 269
    sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop() line: 212
    sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run() line: 176
  ]
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's your code, you can simply construct an Exception at the time of constructing the object:

```
public class MyObject {
   public final Exception creationPoint = new Exception();

   ...
}
```

Then, creationPoint.printStackTrace() will print the creation point (or you can call getStackTrace() to query it programmatically). As GhostCat points out, collecting the stack trace (which happens on construction of the Exception object) of course has a performance hit, so you would generally use this technique judiciously to investigate a specific issue with objects that are generated relatively infrequently.

Comment: You understand that a jvm might decide to stop collecting stack traces when such requests come in too frequently? Indiscriminately creating stack trace information is a terrible idea.

Comment: Well, I didn't say you should do it indiscriminately... As you rightly say, there is potentially a performance hit. As with pretty much any profiling/instrumentation technique, there is a performance tradeoff to be considered. In many cases, if they were objects generated so frequently that this was an issue, you'd probably also need to employ additional techniques (e.g. only take the trace every 1000 instances) simply to avoid unnecessary logging/collection. Nonetheless, it's a valid technique that has its uses.

Answer (score 1):

JFR may be what you need, the tool can capture stack information when an object is created, but it seems to capture only part of the all objects.